# Add new spatial reference to ArcGIS with WKT

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, well-known-text

I'm working with a layer on ArcMap with a spatial reference that is not included in ArcMap. How can I create and add the spatial reference because I already know its WKT?

I use ArcMap 10.3

Comment: By what do you mean "not included"?  Is this just a matter of parameters, or do you mean an unsupported projection? You probably ought to share the WKT.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-spatial-reference.htm might help, you should be able to grab the spatial reference directly from the layer. Before you do though make sure that the spatial reference parameters are not the same as an existing spatial reference with an EPSG or SRID code, WKT can express a known spatial reference without this code but be exactly the same parameters - it is better to redefine as the known spatial reference to help project-on-the-fly and defined transformations to operate smoothly.

Comment: I tried Michael's suggestion and it works. I had to find a layer in that spatial reference and copy it.